# Using ZURB Reveal Modal Plugin to control Youtube video

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement an embedded Youtube video with the [ZURB Reveal Modal Plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin).

So far I have the following which works and pauses the video upon closing the modal window using ".modal-close". However, when clicking ".modal-bg" it is not working :( Any idea why? Likewise I would like to close the modal window after the video has finished playing.

```
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    $(".modal-close, .modal-bg").on('click', function() {
        player.stopVideo();
    });
}

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

**I set up a fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/M53GQ/8/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is addressable by jQuery's way of handling event delegation. Basically, because the element with class `.modal-bg` is created *after* the binding takes place, it doesn't trigger the call to stop the video. Instead, you should use the delegate function on the document body, so that when the click event bubbles up it can detect the right class match even for elements that are created after the initial binding. In other words, change your `onPlayerReady` function to look like this:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    $("body").delegate('.modal-close,.modal-bg','click', function() {
        player.stopVideo();
    });
}
```

To close the modal when the video is done, you'll need to set up an `onStateChange` handler for the player. First, add this to your `events` parameter when creating the YT.Player object:

```
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
```

Then define the callback:

```
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      // close your modal here
    }
  }
```